# How to convert list to float in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a program to look for lines of the form

```
New Revision: 39772
```

extract all the numbers, and then find the average. Here is my code:

```
import re
import statistics

file_name = raw_input("Enter file: ")
file = open(file_name)
revision_nums = []

for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall("New Revision: (\d+)", line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        revision_nums.append(x)

print statistics.mean(revision_nums)
```

However, I realized that all the elements in revision_nums are stored as lists, and I'm getting this error when I try to run it:

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator
```

I tried:

```
for i in revision_nums:
    for j in i:
        j = float(j)
```

and it returns the same error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is the `list`, even if `re.findall` found only one match. Try `revision_nums.append(x[0])`

Comment: x[0] was a string, so I used `revision_nums.append(float(x[0]))`

Answer (score 1):

If your lines always start with `New Revision:` you don't need a regex, you can use str.startswith and str.rsplit:

```
file_name = raw_input("Enter file: ")
with open(file_name) as f:
    revision_nums = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("New Revision:"):
            revision_nums.append(float(line.rsplit(None,1)[1]))
```

Which can become a list comp:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
      revision_nums = [float(line.rsplit(None,1)[1])for line in f 
                      if line.startswith("New Revision:")]
```

Using `with` will automatically close your file.

If you have to use re and might have many matches in a line use search and `extend`, mapping to float:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    revision_nums = []
    r = re.compile("New Revision:\s+(\d+)")
    for line in f:
         revision_nums.extend(map(float,r.findall(line)))
```